# メーリンググループリストの取得　200以上が取得できない。

Tags: c#, google-api

```
using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1;
using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

# Code

GroupsResource.ListRequest groupsResourceRequest = service.Groups.List();
groupsResourceRequest.Customer = customer;
IList<Group> g = groupsResourceRequest.Execute().GroupsValue;
```

この方法では200件までしか取得できません。

googleのgithubで質問したところGoogle.Apis.Drive.v3を使うようなアドバイスがあったのですが、この２つがどのように結びつけるのか見当がつきません

https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/905
https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/0fe663bb9796acd875b676a9f1423a48

何かアドバイスが頂ければと思います。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！ 質問にあるコードは、githubにあるものと多少違いますがそれでOKですか？ 質問は自分で編集できますので、もし間違っていれば修正をお願いいたします。合わせて、各行の行頭に半角スペースを4つ入れることでコードブロックの修飾ができますので、お試し下さい。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/63226

Answer (score 1):

リンク先で説明されているのは結果の`NextPageToken`を使用して複数回リクエストを発行しろということだと思います。

```
// 複数回リクエストを行うので、各リクエストの結果をまとめるリストを宣言する。
List<Group> list = new List<Group>();
string pageToken = null;
while (true)
{
    GroupsResource.ListRequest groupsResourceRequest = service.Groups.List();
    groupsResourceRequest.Customer = customer;
    // 2回目以降のリクエストでは前回得たNextPageTokenを設定する。
    groupsResourceRequest.PageToken = pageToken;

    Groups groups = groupsResourceRequest.Execute();
    IList<Group> g = groups.GroupsValue;

    // 今回のリクエストの結果をリストに追加する。
    list.AddRange(g);
    // 次回リクエスト用のPageTokenを保管する。
    pageToken = groups.NextPageToken;

    // トークンがなければ処理終了   
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageToken) || !g.Any())
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: アドバイス、ありがとうございます。　正しく動作しました。

Comment: @107User 解決したのであれば「回答の承認」を行ってください http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer